# 1000 custom data items, typed array views or data views?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I'm some confused with this.

Imagine I have :
item = x,y,z,id,type,ref  (4 4 4 1 1 2 bytes  = 16 bytes ) 
I want 1000 items so I create an arraybuffer of 16000 bytes.

I can use typed arrays or dataviews. ( with their offsets)
I want to :

- access data from 0 to 9999 ( for example to draw the points or to create something )
- access to a specific item, for example  the 134th.
- fast write & read operations on data, file or network.

My question is : what is best?

1. use Dataview -> get & set with offsets
2. use typed array simple views  with offsets

I think I'm going to have any kind of OS using my app. so I need to force an endian approach.

With all this elements, what is your opinion ? Thanks

Comment: An array of plain objects is not fast enough?

Comment: I have (I must) to save / read the data to a binary file, so I can't use objects.

Comment: For that, the DataView seems to be the option of choice

Comment: mmm . This is very interesting http://jsperf.com/dataview-vs-typed-array-views